# How to change the default limit 25 in Neo4j community

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j Community version, when click on a node label, it will auto generate/run cypher script.

```
MATCH (n:`Person`) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

Is there a way to change the default number 25?

Comment: Nope there is no browser configuration for it. Anyway changing the number manually is not worth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can't.
If you look at html of neo4j browser, you will see:

```
ng-click="editor.execScript('MATCH n RETURN n LIMIT 25')"
```

And I think it's not customizable

Comment: right it's not configurable. Either you rebuild Neo4j from source with different value or use something like tampermonkey to tweak javascript in the browser.